# Jest Enzyme test a React component that returns null in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that returns null in render under certain conditions:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.isHidden) {
      return null;
  }

  return <div>test</div>;
}
```

I want to check if the component is null when isHidden is true with jest and enzyme:

```
describe('myComp', () => {
    it('should not render if isHidden is true', () => {
        const comp = shallow(<myComp isHidden={true} />);
        expect(comp.children().length).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

This works but is there a more idiomatic way to write this test ? Testing for components that render as null is quite a common scenario.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```js
expect(comp.type()).toEqual(null)
```

That's it!

or:

```js
expect(comp.get(0)).toBeFalsy()
```

Comment: Maybe it's an artifact of `mount` versus `shallow`, but this did not work for me, I had to look at `comp.html()` as described by @shoaib-nawaz.

Comment: `expect(comp.get(0)).toBeFalsy()` **worked** for me. `expect(comp.type()).toEqual(null)`did **not**.

Answer (score 83):

`ShallowWrapper` has a [`isEmptyRender()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/isEmptyRender.html) function:

```
expect(comp.isEmptyRender()).toBe(true)
```

Comment: Best answer in my eyes.

Comment: @klugjo - this is a better answer than the accepted answer. Can you change the accepted answer?

Comment: This answer best communicates the substance of the test while also accurately testing the result.

Answer (score 28):

According to [`ShallowWrapper::html`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/9c562b105ae8c7c0729da5eed588bf15e63f7e30/packages/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L832) implementation
it returns null if component instance type is null, as a result of `render`.

```
expect(comp.html()).toBeNull();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: using Chai, `expect(comp.html()).to.eq('')` worked for me

Comment: This did not work for me, `comp.html()` returned an empty string in my case.

Answer (score 9):

we use the following with jest-enzyme

```
expect(comp).toBeEmptyRender()
```

Comment: I was using mocha and chai for that particular project, but thats good to know

Comment: I think you're looking for toBeEmptyRender() to be on comp. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957248/3843358

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Benjamin Intal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957248/12484), I tried to use `myComponent.isEmptyRender()`, but it was unexpectedly returning `false`, even though `myComponent.children().length` was returning 0.

The problem turned out to be that `myComponent` was coming from a call to `.find()` on another shallow-rendered component. In this situation, an extra call to `.shallow()` on the found child component is necessary to get `isEmptyRender()` to work properly:

```
const parentComponent = shallow(<MyParentComponent isMyChildHidden={true} />);
const childComponent = parentComponent.find('MyChildComponent');

expect(childComponent.shallow().isEmptyRender()).toBe(true);
```

Reference: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1278

Comment: For me, calling _shallow()_ on not existing child results in "Method “shallow” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead."
_expect(childComponent.isEmptyRender()).toBe(true)_ works perfectly fine.
enzyme@^3.11.0 & jest-enzyme@^7.1.2